# Screen Flickering with NVIDIA drivers

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, compton

I've recently set up my own Arch linux installation. I'm having some problems with one of the monitors in my dual monitor setup. Every once in a while, seemingly at random, my monitor will go black for a second before refreshing. This is pretty frustrating. It only happens with one of my monitors, the other monitor is completely unaffected. I have tried all sort of things and read loads of forum posts, but I'm unable to fix this problem.

I am running the nvidia-450 driver, with a GTX 1080 TI. The problem monitor is connected over displayport and is a 2k monitor. The other monitor is also connected over displayport and is a 1080p monitor.

Here are some command outputs that might help, edited for relevant sections:

`lspci - k`

```
08:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 374c
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

`dmesg`

```
[    5.896505] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  450.66  Wed Aug 12 19:37:58 UTC 2020
[    5.947554] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000800] Loading driver
[    5.947559] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:08:00.0 on minor 0
[    6.031959] audit: type=1130 audit(1598214227.195:21): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=nvidia-persistenced comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[    6.034669] usb 1-5: set resolution quirk: cval->res = 384
[    6.034934] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device <unnamed> (046d:0825)
[    6.119775] uvcvideo 1-5:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
[    6.119779] uvcvideo 1-5:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 6 was not initialized!
[    6.119781] uvcvideo 1-5:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 7 was not initialized!
[    6.119783] uvcvideo 1-5:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[    6.119785] uvcvideo 1-5:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 3 was not initialized!
[    6.119787] uvcvideo 1-5:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[    6.119882] input: UVC Camera (046d:0825) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/input/input32
[    6.119971] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    6.119972] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[    6.135659] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[    7.092020] audit: type=1103 audit(1598214228.255:22): pid=541 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_env,pam_permit acct="lightdm" exe="/usr/bin/lightdm" hostname=? addr=? terminal=:0 res=success'
[    7.114373] audit: type=1130 audit(1598214228.278:23): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=user-runtime-dir@976 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[    7.124372] audit: type=1101 audit(1598214228.288:24): pid=545 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_access,pam_unix,pam_permit,pam_time acct="lightdm" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[    7.124392] audit: type=1103 audit(1598214228.288:25): pid=545 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=? acct="lightdm" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
[    7.124425] audit: type=1006 audit(1598214228.288:26): pid=545 uid=0 old-auid=4294967295 auid=976 tty=(none) old-ses=4294967295 ses=1 res=1
[    7.743903] igb 0000:06:00.0 enp6s0: igb: enp6s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[    7.956953] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp6s0: link becomes ready
[    9.320055] usb 5-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   24.893783] usb 5-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   25.123356] usb 5-4: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[   30.440070] usb 5-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   46.013782] usb 5-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   46.120071] usb usb5-port4: attempt power cycle
[   46.763345] usb 5-4: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   51.863777] xhci_hcd 0000:09:00.3: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[   57.197078] xhci_hcd 0000:09:00.3: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[   57.403701] usb 5-4: device not accepting address 5, error -62
[   57.526684] usb 5-4: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[   62.530134] xhci_hcd 0000:09:00.3: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[   67.863370] xhci_hcd 0000:09:00.3: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[   68.070345] usb 5-4: device not accepting address 6, error -62
[   68.070416] usb usb5-port4: unable to enumerate USB device
[   71.757209] kauditd_printk_skb: 5 callbacks suppressed
```

Let me know if you need any more info. This problem has been driving me crazy.

Comment: External links are generally discouraged.  It's very possible that the link will expire, preventing someone in the future from determining if they have the same problem.  Can you extract the interesting parts of those outputs and edit this question to include them?

Comment: @Stewart I've removed the links

Comment: add the kernel parameter `nouveau.enable_psr=0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, my screen flickering problem was caused by my compositor: picom.
I solved this problem by changing my backend from glx to xrender in my picom configuration file.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tyried switching to the open source drivers? These are less likely to have issues due to the amount of people working on them. If not, it may just be that your graphics card isn't getting enough power.

Comment: Yes, I've tried using the open source Nouveau drivers, the same problem occurs. Oddly enough, I dual boot this system, and my Windows installation doesn't experience these problems at all, making me think it isn't a power problem. If it was, what steps could I take to figure that out?

Comment: Does the screen flicker when you are sitting at idle on the desktop? Or is it only when you put it under load. A good way to test if it is a power issue is to run GPU Test (Google it).

Comment: The screen seems to flicker completely at random. Even when I'm on idle with no windows open or intense background processes running (that I know of) the screen will flicker. Sometimes it will flicker every few seconds and sometimes it will be stable for a while, I haven't been able to discern a pattern. I'll run a GPU test now and update the question with my results.

Comment: I've run a few different gpu tests and none of them seem to have any problem. My GPU performed well on all of them, and it didn't seem like they caused increased flickering.

Comment: The nouveau driver doesn't properly support Pascal generation cards. The last series of cards it properly supports is Kepler (GTX 700). Also, *due to the amount of people working on them* is a claim you need to find some very good confirmations because from what I've heard the nouveau project is severely understaffed.